# Selecting Rows at Sub-Total Breaks

Tags: vba, excel

I was hoping to incorporate a formatting script into my VBA macro whenever I hit a subtotaling row. I plan for the code to insert a spacing row between the new port numbers then box from column E to M.

My issue, however, is that the specific port numbers pulled into the spreadsheet are based on a variable previously established in an earlier part of the script and are different each time the macro is ran.

So in short, my question is - Is there a way to code the macro to search column E for each port total row and continue this process until all port total rows have been found?

Thank you for any insight/answers in advance! Please let me know if I need to clarify anything!

*Update - some possible code I have been playing with:

```
Columns("E:E").Select

Selection.Find(What:="Total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    ActiveCell.Select

   'Here is where I want to select from the current cell in Column E to Column M, the active cell will not consistently be the same so I am not sure how to select the range from Column E to M
    'It will not always be E14 as shown next 

    Range("E14:M14").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    'Now I need to repeat the above until all cells in Column E with "Total" in them have been formatted. Is there a way to loop it until it finds a previously formatted "Total" row?
```

End Sub

Comment: I apologize pnuts, I am not sure how to go about setting my image/file to a link. If it is easier for everyone I can certainly send an email to someone who can post the image or file here.

Comment: I apologize, I can't find a site that I can upload with at work (we have a bit of online security). I guess I will have to try to access a site when I get home tonight. Sorry for the delay. Is there anything specifically that I can maybe clear up verbally?

Comment: Yea I didn't do a very good job about describing my predicament, I was really hoping the picture would clarify! What I was hoping to do was search Column E for a cell using "Total", then if it does have "Total" in it select the entire row (at which point I would do some formatting). Then continue this process until all "Total"s had been formatted.  

I will be sure to try and get a set of pictures to explain my goal tonight tho, thanks for being patient!!

Comment: Oh sorry, I was hoping to do the process using VBA. I was hoping I could get the macro to search Column E for all rows containing "Total" then for each cell containing "Total" select from that cell over to Column M and bold box that range. I could certainly live without including the space between portfolio numbers (it would have just been the icing on the cake :D  )

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks for your time and insight pnuts, take care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

This uses the find function to search the range for the word "Total", selects it and the 9 (I counted 8 but whatever excel) cells to the right of it (E-M), and makes them bold.

You can add additional formatting options under the bold if you want

```
Sub FormatTotalLines()
Dim SearchRange, First, Finder As Range
Set SearchRange = Range("E:E") 'Search This Range
Set Finder = SearchRange.Find("Total")
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
First = Finder.Address
Do
    With Finder.Resize(, 9)
        .Font.Bold = True
        'Additional formatting here
        'Make the row green, for example
        .Interior.Color = RGB(230, 250, 230)
    End With
    Set Finder = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=Finder)
Loop While Not Finder Is Nothing And Finder.Address <> First
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

**Edits:**

For borders, you can use this to clear them:

```
.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```

Side note, to clear the green coloring:

```
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```

Then you can add:

```
.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Borders.Weight = xlMedium '(or xlThin, or xlThick)
```

If you just want an outside border

```
.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous 
.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Change the outside weights:

```
.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium '(or xlThin, or xlThick)
.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium '(or xlThin, or xlThick)
.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium '(or xlThin, or xlThick)
.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium '(or xlThin, or xlThick)
```

The final code to apply a thick box border (and bold the font) would then become:

```
With Finder.Resize(, 8)
    .Font.Bold = True           'Bold the font
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'Clear any previous borders - not always necessary
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
End With
```

**Just copy and paste this whole macro and use:**

```
Sub FormatTotalLines()
Dim SearchRange, First, Finder As Range
Set SearchRange = Range("E:E") 'Search This Range
Set Finder = SearchRange.Find("Total")
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Speeds it up a lot
First = Finder.Address
Do
    With Finder.Resize(, 9)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Set Finder = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=Finder)
Loop While Not Finder Is Nothing And Finder.Address <> First
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Speeds it up a lot
End Sub
```

Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVnBz.png

Comment: I'm really sorry to keep bugging you with my issues but could you help me figure out how to replace the green fill with a bold box around the range? I'm am trying to insert the bit from my code above into yours where you fill with green but nothing is happening? Again, thanks so much for your time and insight

Comment: OK so maybe I am not using the code correctly but I am getting vertical border lines between each cell, is there a way I can re write it to set a border as if the cells from E - M were highlighted together?  Again, sorry to keep pestering you with these questions. I really appreciate the insight

Comment: No problem, use the final code at the very bottom. Here are my results when using it: http://i.imgur.com/0bm77KH.png

Comment: I pasted a "final" version at the very bottom that is the entire macro u can copy and paste. I also added Application.ScreenUpdating = False and True which speeds up execution a lot

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks so much for taking the time to help me! Once I get a few more reputation points I will be sure to come back and vote up your answer ( I don't have enough points yet lol ) Thanks and take care